# Django queryset group by and count for related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this models with this relations

```
class Product(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(
        _("Code"),
        max_length=50,
        unique=True
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        max_length=150
    )


class ProductOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_("Product"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='options')
    vtype = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(_("Text"), max_length=50)
```

With this example data

```
prod1 = Product(code='1', name='Name 1')
ProductOption(product=prod1, vtype='Color', text='Blue')
ProductOption(product=prod1, vtype='Size', text='M')
ProductOption(product=prod1, vtype='Material', text='Cotton')

prod2 = Product(code='2', name='Name 2')
ProductOption(product=prod2, vtype='Color', text='Red')
ProductOption(product=prod2, vtype='Size', text='X')
ProductOption(product=prod2, vtype='Material', text='Cotton')

prod3 = Product(code='3', name='Name 3')
ProductOption(product=prod3, vtype='Color', text='Red')
ProductOption(product=prod3, vtype='Size', text='L')
ProductOption(product=prod3, vtype='Material', text='Cotton')
```

How can I build a query from Product with the ORM with this result

Example:

```
Product.objects.filter(name__icontains='some text').values('options__vtype', 'options__text').annotate(count=Count())

[
    {'options__vtype': 'Color', 'options__text': 'Blue', 'count': 1},
    {'options__vtype': 'Color', 'options__text': 'Red', 'count': 2},
    {'options__vtype': 'Size', 'options__text': 'M', 'count': 1},
    {'options__vtype': 'Size', 'options__text': 'X', 'count': 1},
    {'options__vtype': 'Size', 'options__text': 'L', 'count': 1},
    {'options__vtype': 'Material', 'options__text': 'Cotton', 'count': 3},
]
```

I test a lot of options like using Concat, and Count but I fail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProductOption.objects.values('vtype', 'text').annotate(count=Count('*'))
```